# Enabling wordpress multisite breaks database connection

Tags: php, database, wordpress, multisite

I am attempting to set up a local instance of an existing multisite and am having issues with the setup.

I have confirmed that all of my database login information is correct and defined in the config like so (I set up my local databases using Homestead) :

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'homestead');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

This works perfectly fine up until I initiate the multisite settings. Adding this info to the `wp-config.php` file gives me an `Error establishing a database connection` result on the page:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'testsite.test');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Why does it work when it isn't defined as a multisite?

I've made sure to have the multisite definitions above the "stop editing" line as well

**EDIT:**

It seems to be caused by the following line:

`define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');`

However removing it causes the site to redirect to the production version, even though I have made sure to set `siteurl` and `home` to the local url in the database???